# Create a specific number of HTML elements in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, matrix

I want to create a form that gets a number from the user and dynamically creates `input` elements based on that number. I tried following codes, but without any result:

HTML:

```
<input type="number" id="row"/>
<button type="submit" onclick="matrix(document.getElementById('row').value)">
 OK</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
function matrix(row){
  for(var i=0; i<=row;i++){
  var s = "<input type='number' id='row'+i />";
  var div = document.createElement('div');
  div.innerHTML = s;
  var elements = div.childNodes;
  }
}
```

Comment: what happens with your code?  Are you checking that row.value is what you think it is, and that your loop is working?  I also don't see you appending any of the new input elements onto the DOM.

Comment: Try `"<input type='number' id='row" + i + "' />"`. And also, append it to the DOM somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You never add the inputs you created to the DOM. Also, you are constantly overriding the value of the `elements` variable.

Also, a better solution might be using the DOM APIs instead of setting `innerHTML`:

```
function matrix(row) {
   var count = parseInt(row, 10);
   var inputs = [], input;

   for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
     input = document.createElement("input");
     input.id   = "row" + i;
     input.type = "number";
     inputs.push(input);
   }

   // Add the proper selector here
   var target = document.querySelector("form");
   inputs.forEach(function(input) {
      target.appendChild(input);
   });
}
```

Example: http://jsbin.com/valom/1/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<input type="number" id="row" />
<button type="submit" onclick="matrix(document.getElementById('row').value)">
    OK</button>
<div id="test"></div>

<script>
    function matrix(row) {
        for (var i = 0; i <= row; i++) {
            var s = "<input type='number' id='row" + i + "' />";
            var div = document.getElementById('test');
            div.innerHTML += s;
        }
    }
</script>
```